# how to get thinned character image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am performing Thinning operation on Gujarati character using neural networks. after train neural network I get the blurred image. SO, I want the Thinned image from blur image.The blurred image has the medial pixel of the stroke is much brighter than adjacent pixel. so My task is how to extract medial pixel which is part of the thinned image.

here, There are two images give below one is input blur image and the second image is Thinned image which I want from the blurred image. please give me the suggestion.

Input blur image :

[image]

Output Image :

[image]

Comment: Perform binarization followed by thinning.

Comment: Another viable approach is non-maximum suppression.

Comment: I think that earlier I didn't explain my question properly. So now, I have updated my question. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please take a look.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, I know non-maximum suppression but never implement it. can you give me the brief suggestion how it works in my case?